save return value sinl function
My problem is that I don't understand what starts happening in the stack from line 27. <br(The code is compiled on godbolt.org) <br<br<br
Below I will give part of the code in assembler and C <br
Assembler: <br<br<br
calc_integ:
            pushq   %rbp
            movq    %rsp, %rbp
            addq    $-128, %rsp
            movq    %rdi, -88(%rbp)
            movl    $0, -44(%rbp)
            fldz
            fstpt   -16(%rbp)
            fldt    .LC1(%rip)
            fstpt   -64(%rbp)
            fildl   -44(%rbp)
            fldt    -64(%rbp)
            fsubp   %st, %st(1)
            fildq   -88(%rbp)
            cmpq    $0, -88(%rbp)
            jns     .L2
            fldt    .LC2(%rip)
            faddp   %st, %st(1)
    .L2:
            fdivrp  %st, %st(1)
            fstpt   -80(%rbp)
            fildl   -44(%rbp)
            fstpt   -32(%rbp)
            movq    $0, -40(%rbp)
            jmp     .L3
    .L4:
            pushq   -24(%rbp) <- This is where I don't understand
            pushq   -32(%rbp)
            call    sinl
            addq    $16, %rsp
            fstpt   -112(%rbp)
            pushq   -24(%rbp)
            pushq   -32(%rbp)
            call    expl
            addq    $16, %rsp
            fldt    -112(%rbp)
            fmulp   %st, %st(1)
            fstpt   -112(%rbp)
            fldt    -32(%rbp)
            fldt    -80(%rbp)
            faddp   %st, %st(1)
            leaq    -16(%rsp), %rsp
            fstpt   (%rsp)
            call    sinl
            addq    $16, %rsp
            fstpt   -128(%rbp)
            fldt    -32(%rbp)
            fldt    -80(%rbp)
            faddp   %st, %st(1)
            leaq    -16(%rsp), %rsp
            fstpt   (%rsp)
            call    expl
            addq    $16, %rsp
            fldt    -128(%rbp)
            fmulp   %st, %st(1)
            fldt    -112(%rbp)
            faddp   %st, %st(1)
            fldt    -16(%rbp)
            faddp   %st, %st(1)
            fstpt   -16(%rbp)
            fldt    -32(%rbp)
            fldt    -80(%rbp)
            faddp   %st, %st(1)
            fstpt   -32(%rbp)
            addq    $1, -40(%rbp)
    .L3:
            movq    -40(%rbp), %rax
            cmpq    -88(%rbp), %rax
            jb      .L4
            fldt    -16(%rbp)
            fldt    -80(%rbp)
            fmulp   %st, %st(1)
            fstpt   -16(%rbp)
            fldt    -16(%rbp)
            fldt    .LC3(%rip)
            fdivrp  %st, %st(1)
            fstpt   -16(%rbp)
            fldt    -16(%rbp)
            leave
            ret

c:
    long double calc_integ(unsigned long N) {
        int a = 0;
        long double integral = 0;
        long double b = M_PI;
        long double step = (b - a) / N;
        long double point = a;
        for (size_t k = 0; k < N; k++) {
            integral += sinl(point)*expl(point) + sinl(point + step)*expl(point + step); //<- this //corresponds to the 27th line of assembler code
            point += step;
        }
        integral *= step;
        integral /= 2;
        return integral;
    }

    int main() {
        struct timespec sts, stf;
        unsigned long int N = 0;
        scanf("%ld", &N);
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &sts);
        printf("%lf", calc_integ(N));
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &stf);
        printf("Program execution time: %lf ", stf.tv_sec - sts.tv_sec + 0.000000001 * (stf.tv_nsec - sts.tv_nsec));
        return 0;
    }

Can you please give me a hint or a direction that will help me figure it out, I don’t even know how to google it.
How I reasoned:

Added a value from -24(%rbp) to the top of the stack. But there is garbage stored there, because I drew the stack and nothing is put at this address.
then copy the value of the point to the top of the stack
call the sinl function, which takes the element from the top of the stack as an argument, that is point. And its return value sinl will be saved in the address where the garbage was previously stored. The same thing happens with exp.
But then I see the multiplication of st(1) and st. The only thing that can be multiplied here is sinl and exp. But how did these values ​​get into fpu?
I have an assumption that the return values ​​of the functions sinl and exp are saved in fpu. But then, what happens on the stack?


Godbolt should show you which source line each asm instruction is associated with.
sinl only takes one arg, but it's a 16-byte long double (only the low 10 bytes are useful, but x86-64 SysV uses alignof(long double) = sizeof(long double) = 16).   fstpt   -32(%rbp) stores 10 bytes, not just 8.  pushq  -24(%rbp) pushes the top 2 value bytes and 6 more bytes of padding.  It might be easier to track what's going on if you compiled with at least -Og optimization; How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?

https://godbolt.org/z/ePrqTa8GE shows -O2 code-gen being about 60 instead of 80 instructions. And that -Wall shows a format-string mismatch: %lf expects a double.  You want %Lf for a long double.  https://godbolt.org/z/dcz8he5bn shows it printing sensible output after fixing that bug.

The same thing happens with exp. - no it doesn't, after call expl, there's a fldt    -112(%rbp) to reload the sinl return value, opposite of after sinl which stored to space.  Before that load, expl's return value was in %st(0) (aka %st, the top of the x87 register stack); after it's in %st(1).  (In the x86-64 System V calling convention, long double values are returned in x87 registers; in i386 System V, float and double were also returned that way but x86-64 SysV uses XMM registers for those.)

I'd recommend writing simpler code like long double foo(){return 1.0;} or void bar(){volatile long double x = sinl(1.0);} if you're not sure what calling convention GCC is using.  (Or read the calling convention doc, but simple experiments are easier.)

https://web.archive.org/web/20190723173250/http://ray.masmcode.com/tutorial/index.html is an excellent tutorial if you're not familiar with x87 and its stack registers.  (Which are totally unrelated to stack memory, so it's important to use clear terminology in contexts when both are involved.)

@PeterCordes (thanks for trying to explain the code to me) so, in the register %st(0) there is a variable point, then the sinl function is called and saves its value in %st(0). (the value of the variable point no longer exists in fpu). The line fstpt -112(%rbp) saves the return value of sinl from fpu to the specified address. From this I conclude that fpu is empty. The expl function is called, but how does it understand that it needs to take point as an argument?

The calling convention passes FP args in memory, on the asm stack pointed-to by RSP.
So the callee will do fldt 8(%rsp) if it doesn't alloc any stack space.  I thought that's what you meant by takes the element from the top of the stack as an argument!  A more sophisticated calling convention could have passed one FP arg in x87 stack registers, but x87 is inconvenient for the general case of many FP args: you don't know which arg the callee wants to process first.  x87 is basically deprecated for most uses in x86-64, so the calling convention didn't make a lot of effort being fancy.

Also note that the x87 stack is always empty before a call, e.g. fstpt   (%rsp) right before call sinl to empty it and store the arg on the stack.  That lets callees always know they can use all 8 x87 register slots if they want; the architects were optimistic that the register-stack design would lead to less save/restore since a function runs the same whether 0 or 3 registers are already in use... unless it uses more than 5 regs or in turn tries to nest.  That might work for hand-written asm with funcs that know about each other, but actual calling conventions for C must not fail.
